# What are some effects of higher than usual cooling system pressure?

Tags: coolant, cooling-system

This is a follow on to [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/54883/how-can-an-a-c-system-consume-coolant-when-in-use/54894#54894) where I asked how A/C could be causing coolant loss.

The answer was that using the A/C can cause higher than usual cooling system pressure, which could result in coolant leaking from the radiator cap (if the cap is ageing and faulty).

My question is, what are some other effects of higher than usual cooling system pressures, particularly for important components like the water pump, timing belt, and coolant hoses, and the engine in general. How would these effects become noticeable and how would they evolve over the short term and the long time?

Comment: If the radiator cap is functioning correctly, you won't have over pressure in the system. It will allow pressure to escape without causing harm to the other portions of the engine (like the hoses). You would lose coolant to the overflow, but this should be sucked back in when the coolant system cools off.